# Add configurable field to workflow builded in VS

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I have created a workflow in VS which doing some logic. I would like to add some configurable text field so that the SharePoint administrators can change it.

For example this is a text field with the name "EmailAddress". An administrator sets this field to some email address (e.g. test@test.nl). If the workflow starts, one of the steps is to send an email. This will be the configurable email address.

This field must be available in SharePoint, somewhere at the workflow instance.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the workflow do?  It's easy enough to plug different columns into the workflow depending upon your aim.

For your example, you could use a People / Group column that links to AD, have results returned as email addresses or stored in a variable that's then used elsewhere.  This sort of stuff is fairly easy to do in SPD so it'll be achievable with VS.

Comment: It is not needed that complexity. Only a simple textfield which is available for the SharePoint administrator.

I need something like when you build a webpart, it is possible to add custom properties. These custom properties are available for SharePoint administrators. The value of these custom properties are also available in the code of the webpart.

Comment: Someone told me something about associated columns. Is this also a good solution to build a field which is managable in SharePoint?